# how to joining muiltiple select query without common column?

Tags: sql

I want to combine multiple columns of different select queries(all return 2 column and 1 row). How can I do it?

for example

```
select p.* from(
   (select a.id, a.global from table1 as a)
   (select j.gogl, j.popl from table2 as j)
) as p
```

It have multiple select but they all return 2 column and only 1 row

Expected output

| id | global | gogl | popl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row | First | row |

Comment: Please don't tag multiple conflicting RDBMS. Only tag the one you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a single row is guaranteed, just combining the output of each select into 4 columns you can use a `full join` with an always true condition - that way you'll always get the value from one if the other happens to return null.

```
select * from
    (select id, global from table1) as a
full join
    (select gogl, popl from table2) as j
on 1=1
```

Comment: just had to add an alias in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all combinations of rows from the two tables, then use:

```
select a.id, a.global, j.gogl, j.popl
from table1 a cross join
     table2 j
```

Note:  If all the tables have 1 row, then the result set will have one row.  However, the number of rows can grow or shrink dramatically, depending on the size of the tables.  If any table has no rows, for instance, the result set has no rows.